# Why does this code open in a new window after the signed in?

Tags: html

Here is my code. My problem is that when I click to Sign In it signs me in a new tab. How can I make this code to keep the content in the same window?
Do I must use iframe? Thanks.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http:/something.different.com/my_profile/do_login" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
     <h1>Sign In</h1>
     <div class="login-fields">
      <p>Sign in using ticket number and last name:</p>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Ticket Number:</label>
        <input class="login password-field" id="ticket_number" name="ticket_number" placeholder="Ticket #" type="text" />
      </div> <!-- /field -->
      <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="login username-field" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
      </div> <!-- /password -->
      </div> <!-- /login-fields -->
      <div class="login-actions">
        <input class="button btn btn-warning btn-large" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
     </div> <!-- .actions -->
    </form>
```

Comment: There's no PHP here..maybe you have JS do something?

Comment: your HTML code above have no specified target so it should submit on the same "tab". it have to be 'something else' in your page that taking over the submit. Maybe some javascript. Try to take the code above ONLY and place it in test.html page on your server. submit and see if that it will submit your data via POST back on the same Tab.

Comment: question's unclear; voted to close as such

Answer (score 0):

Add form target="_self"

ex, `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http:/something.different.com/my_profile/do_login" target="_self" method="post">`